# Should I use Ant or Gradle to build an Android project using the command line?

Tags: android, windows, build, cmd

I want to create a new android project with command line (in windows) and compile it.

Should I use Ant or Gradle ?

I have made copy from another project but I want to build it with a command.

```
public class serveur {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(" debut class serveur");
        //copier android original
        Copy_projet.copyFullRecursive(new File("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/exécution/Partie2DeProjet/Android originale"), new File("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/exécution/Partie2DeProjet/nouvelleApplication"));
        System.out.println(" projet crée");
        //recevoire les informations de la part du client android
        SocketFromClient.received();
        System.out.println(" information reçu");
        //copie le xml layout et main.java
        Test.layout(); 
        System.out.println(" xml et main copie ");
        //modifie le manifest
        Modify_manifest.dom();
        System.out.println(" le manifest a était modifie ");
        //envoyer apk vers application android
        SocketToClient.go();

        System.out.println("fin class serveur ");
    }
}
```

Comment: "i should use ant or gradel ?" -- use Gradle. I am not aware that Google is trying to keep Ant support going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is not an android project. It's an incomplete java program. Android projects don't need a main method like regular java programs - it specifies a launchpoint in the AndroidManifest file. Assuming you have more code with this (where are the imports?), and you have the java [jdk](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/), you could run it (assuming your file is named serveur.java) using

```
javac serveur.java
java serveur
```

[Look here](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html) for more on running java programs.

If you indeed have an Android program, that is unrelated to the code you posted, the building is a little more complicated, and I recommend using an IDE (Eclipse, Android Studio). It's possible to build from cmd line but it's more complicated for an android project. You will need to use a build tool like ant or gradle.

[Look here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html) for managing Android projects in command line

[Look here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) for running your android project from command line

Once again, if you want to create android projects, you should really use a development environment like Android studio.

Comment: i know it is a java project i copy how copy un android project to creat a new android project and it is just a main i have other class. but my question is how to creat a new project android whith command ligne cmd. ant gradle or apktool . i am forced to use commande line , what should i use?. thank you.